# How do i remove a pointer to an object in c++ from a vector dynamically?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, vector, element

Okay, so i'm doing this game like a project where i have 3 different objects.

```
void Character::shoot(){
  Shot* s = new Shot(blablabla);
  shots.push_back(s);
}
```

This happens dynamically, and currently i dont delete the pointers so it has to be loads of pointers to shots in that vector after a little while.

I use Bot, Character and Shot, and as i said i need help with storing and removing a pointer to the shot dynamically, preferably from a vector. I've got it to work like i put all the shot objects in a vector, but they never disappear from there. And i want to delete them permanently from my program when they collide with something, or reaches outside my screen width.

Comment: Do you really need pointers? If not, then the easiest solution is not to use them Use `std::vector<Shot> shots;`.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` that way `.remove()`-ing it from the vector should delete it properly. Alternatively just storing the shots directly (no dynamic allocation) should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) and [`std::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) on any std container to remove content:

```
Shot* to_be_removed = ...;
std::vector<Shot*>::iterator i = std::remove(shots.begin(),shots.end(),to_be_removed);
std::erase(i,shots.end());
delete (to_be_removed);//don't forget to delete the pointer
```

This works when you know the element you want to remove. If you don't know the element you must find a way to identify the elements you want removed. Also if you have a system to identify the element it could be easier to use the container iterator in order to do the removal:

```
std::vector<Shot*>::iterator i = ...;//iterator the the element you want to remove
delete (*i);//delete memory
shots.erase(i);//remove it from vector
```

Lastly if you want to remove all pointers from the container and delete all the items at the same time you can use [`std::for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

```
//c++ 03 standard:
void functor(Shot* s)
{
    delete(s);
}

std::for_each(shots.begin(),shots.end(),functor);
shots.clear();//empty the list

//or c++11 standard:
std::for_each(shots.begin(),shots.end(),[] (Shot * s){ delete(s); } );
//the rest is the same
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using simple vector methods

You can iterate trough `std::vector` and use [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) method to remove current shot:

```cpp
std::vector<cls*> shots; // Your vector of shots
std::vector<cls*>::iterator current_shot = shots.begin(); // Your shot to be deleted

while( current_shot < shots.end()){
    if((*current_shot)->needs_to_be_deleted()){
        // Remove item from vector
        delete *current_shot;
        current_shot = shots.erase(current_shot);
    } else {
        (*current_shot)->draw();
         ++current_shot; // Iterate trough vector
    }
}
```

`erase()` returns iterator to next element after removed element so `while` loop is used.

---

### Setting values to `null` and calling [`std::remove()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/)

Note that `std::vector::erase()` reorganize everything after delete items:

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, erasing
>   elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
>   to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new
>   positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the
>   one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence
>   containers (such as list or forward_list).

This way you may end up with `O(n^2)` complexity so you may rather set values to `null` and use [`std::remove()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) <sup>as suggested by juanchopanza in comment, [Erase-Remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)</sup>:

```cpp
int deleted = 0;
for( current_shot = shots.begin(); current_shot < shots.end(); ++current_shot){
    if((*current_shot)->needs_to_be_deleted()){
        // Remove item from vector
        delete *current_shot;
        *current_shot = null;
        ++deleted;
    }
}

if( deleted){
    shots.erase( std::remove(shots.begin(), shots.end(), null));
}
```

---

### Using `std::list`

If you need **large** amount of shot creations and deletions [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) may not be the best structure for containing this kind of list (especially when you want to remove items from the middle):

> Internally, vectors use a dynamically allocated array to store their
>   elements. This array **may need to be reallocated** in order to grow in
>   size when new elements are inserted, which implies allocating a new
>   array and moving all elements to it. This is a relatively expensive
>   task in terms of processing time, and thus, vectors do not reallocate
>   each time an element is added to the container.

<sub>See [link from Raxvan's comment](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list/) for performance comparison.</sub>

You may want to use [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) instead:

> List containers are implemented as doubly-linked lists; Doubly linked
>   lists can store each of the elements they contain in different and
>   unrelated storage locations. The ordering is kept by the association
>   to each element of a link to the element preceding it and a link to
>   the element following it.
>
> Compared to other base standard sequence containers (array, vector and
>   deque), *lists perform generally better in inserting, extracting and
>   moving elements in any position within the container for which an
>   iterator has already been obtained*, and therefore also in algorithms
>   that make intensive use of these, like sorting algorithms.
>
> The main drawback of lists and forward_lists compared to these other
>   sequence containers is that they **lack direct access to the elements by
>   their position**;

Which is great for removing items from the middle of the "*array*".

As for removing, use `delete` and [`std::list::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/):

```cpp
std::list<cls*> shots;
std::list<cls*>::iterator current_shot;

// You have to use iterators, not direct access
for( current_shot = shots.begin();  current_shot != shots.end(); current_shot++){
    if( (*current_shots)->needs_to_be_deleted()){
        delete *current_shot;
        shots.erase(current_shot); // Remove element from list
    } 
}
```

---

### Using `std::shared_ptr`

If you have more complex program structure and you use the same object on many places and you can simply determine whether you can delete object already or you need to keep it alive for a little bit more (and if you are using C++11), you can use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) (or use different kind of "smart pointers" which delete data where reference count reaches zero):

```cpp
// Pushing items will have slightly more complicated syntax
std::list< std::shared_ptr<cls>> shots;
shots.push_back( std::shared_ptr( new cls()));
std::list< std::shared_ptr<cls>>::iterator current_shot;

// But you may skip using delete
shots.erase(current_shot); // shared_ptr will take care of freeing the memory
```

Comment: I am not so sure this is good advice. Copying a bunch of pointers is not that expensive. Plus, to remove an item from the middle of the list, you have to find the position first, which is O(N). Furthermore, there is a big overhead in size for lists holding small types (such as pointers). Finally, the data is more fragmented, making it less cache friendly. So you would have to profile first, before making such fundamental changes.

Comment: @juanchopanza I automatically assumed large number of shots shot (which requires large number of items in list) and then removing them in random order (in first round remove shot 1,5,479 and 574; in second round items 10,50,100 and so on). If you could rely on some sort of FIFO/FILO approach, this is an terrible advice... I can also imagine some sort of vector de-fragmentation but it seems even more complicated to me. So due to requirement to remove shots from the middle of the list if suggested list.

Comment: @remyabel My point is that it isn't necessarily better to use a list. The iteration will even be slower. Plus, you can iterate over the vector, marking all pointers to be removed by setting them to `nullptr`, then use erase-remove to get rid of them.

Comment: @Vyktor In all use cases `std::vector` outperforms `std::list` by far especially using small types according to this: http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list/

Comment: @juanchopanza where? deleting?  only if all shots will be deleted all at once, no? how do you propose we should solve this? :) Several (complex) ideas comes to mine.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have a while loop (O(N)) and inside that loop you call erase (O(N)). So, O(N^2) overall. I hinted at an O(N) suggestion in a previous comment to remyabel.

Comment: Almost! You are missing the "erase" part of "erase-remove" :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Blah! Hope I finally got it right. Thanks for your patience ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "delete" to deallocate the memory:

```
vector<Shot*>::iterator i;
for(i = shoot.begin(); i != shoot.end(); ++i)
{
    delete (*i);//delete data that was pointed
    *i = 0;
}
shoot.clear();
```

This will delete all elements from the heap and clear your vector.